# Что в нем не правильно написан? В JavaScipt

Tags: javascript

```js
var o = [1, 7, 8, 12, 17, 21, 28, 32, 35, 47];
var z = [];
var k = [];

function abc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    if (o[i] % 2 == 0) {
      z = o[i];
      console.log(z);
    } else if (o[i] % 2 == 1) {
      k = o[i];
      console.log(k);
    }
  };
};
console.log(z);
```

Comment: var o = [1, 7, 8, 12, 17, 21, 28, 32, 35, 47];
var z=[];
var k=[];

function abc() {
    for (var i=0;i<o.length;i++) {
        if(o[i] % 2 == 0) {
          z=o[i];
            console.log(z);
        }else if(o[i] % 2==1) {
            k=o[i];
            console.log(k);
        }
    };
};
console.log(z);

Comment: опять...опять нужно **тебя** спросить "что в нем неправильно"? и дополни вопрос, нажав "править", а не вставляй код в комментарии

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что что-то неправильно?

Comment: не работает код

Comment: @Алексей,@Grundy спасибо

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку..... не работает код - понятие очень расплывчатое и непонятное абсолютно

Comment: @Алексей спасибо,следующий раз так не буду.

Answer (score 3):

Чую тут две проблемы:

1. тебе надо делать **[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)**, чтобы заносить результат операции в массивы. Т.е. надо писать так:

   ```
   z.push(o[i]);
   ```

   и

   ```
   k.push(o[i]);
   ```
2. ты не вызываешь саму функцию `abc()`, чтобы всё начало работать

```js
var o = [1, 7, 8, 12, 17, 21, 28, 32, 35, 47];
var z = [];
var k = [];

function abc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    if (o[i] % 2 == 0) {
      z.push(o[i]);
      //console.log(z);
    } else if (o[i] % 2 == 1) {
      k.push(o[i]);
      //console.log(k);
    }
  };
};

abc();
console.log(z);
console.log(k);
```

Comment: вызывать функцию abc() это обьязательно?

Comment: @Programmer конечно. чтобы привёлся в движение механизм внутри функции, нужно её вызвать. мне просто интересно: как, по-твоему,  зачем они существуют и какую роль выполняют и для чего ты писал код внутри неё?

Comment: ладно   понятно)))